# How to fix side bar and header using CSS for JS & jQuery Scroller

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, scroller

I have this layout and I want to make the left sidebar, right sidebar and the header fixed.

[image]

This is my css :

```
    #container {
        padding-left: 200px;      /* LC fullwidth */
        padding-right: 190px;     /* RC fullwidth + CC padding */
    }

    #container .column {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }

    #center {
        padding: 10px 20px;       /* CC padding */
        width: 100%;
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }

    #left {
        width: 180px;             /* LC width */
        padding: 0 10px;          /* LC padding */
        right: 240px;             /* LC fullwidth + CC padding */
        margin-left: -100%;
    }

    #right {
        width: 130px;             /* RC width */
        padding: 0 10px;          /* RC padding */
        margin-right: -100%;
    }

    #footer {
        clear: both;
    }
```

& the code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/alibm/nr2NZ/)

After this step, I want to add [nanScrollerJS](http://jamesflorentino.github.com/nanoScrollerJS/) to the right side bar.

I'm not familiar with CSS

Comment: That JSFiddle looks like your diagram to me. What is it that you want to change about it?

Comment: I want to fix header, left and right sidebars.

Comment: Just the #center is not fixed and a user can scroll down.

Comment: For example, like facebook header, it's fixed when I scroll down :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you were trying to do?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nr2NZ/50/)

I've erased almost all of your code and replaced it with new code.

## #fixed

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
```

## #center

```
margin-top: 32px; /* Header height */
padding: 10px 20px; /* CC padding */
box-sizing: border-box;
border-left: 200px solid black; /* LC width including padding */
border-right: 150px solid black; /* RC width including padding */
```

## #left

```
width: 180px; /* LC width */
padding: 0 10px; /* LC padding */
float: left;
```

## #right

```
width: 130px; /* RC width */
padding: 0 10px; /* RC padding */
float: right;
```

## #footer

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `position:fixed`, but, of course, for IE you'll need some hacks to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just fix the center with an absolute height, and then overflow-y.  Here's an example of what I mean:

```
#center {
        padding: 10px 20px;       /* CC padding */
        width: 100%;
        height: 240px;            
        overflow-y:scroll;        
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }
```

and here's a working example (based on yours): http://jsfiddle.net/nr2NZ/27/

Technically the example on nanScrollerJS uses a fixed div on the outside, however in this case, it could because if the outside boxes are position relative, i.e. shouldn't theoretically have an issue.

Comment: In that case, you're going to have to fix the outside positions, as Adrian suggested.  The bigger problem you're going to have is IE rendering the overflow-y: scroll